# Удалить дубликаты из List<T>

Tags: c#, list

Есть список

`List<DB> list = new List<DB();`

Я заношу данные в него, и в конце удаляю дубликаты.

```
 List<DB> liIDs = list.Distinct().ToList<DB>();
```

Но дубли почему то остаются. Как было 4 элемента, так и осталось. Для примера привел содержимое `0` и `2` списка которые по сути и являются дублированными. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 9):

Скорее всего DB это класс, в котором не переопределен `Equals`/`GetHashCode`. По умолчанию эквивалентными считаются те ссылки, которые указывают на один и тот же объект.

Возможные решения:

- Переопределите `Equals` так, чтобы он сравнивал два экземпляра по свойствам. Не забудьте при этом переопределить `GetHashCode` - можно свести его к вызову `GetHashCode` у одного из свойств.
- Реализуйте в классе `DB` интерфейс [`IEquatable<DB>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- Используйте перегрузку `Distinct` которая принимает [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Поменяйте `class DB` на `struct DB` - структуры сравниваются по значению свойств.

Comment: *District* подразумевается `Distinct`

Comment: @Bald56rus спасибо, подправил

Comment: еще можно реализовать интерфейс: [_IEquatable_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, дописал

Answer (score 4):

Для класса DB нужно реализовать `Equals()` и `GetHashCode()`, унаследованные от `object`.